# fancybox 2.1.3 issues: IE & safari

Tags: jquery, fancybox

The site is at http://www.educationinterface.com/

The fancybox image in lower left links to a YT video.

It works fine in FF & Chrome.

In Safari there is extra white space to the right of the video. It corrects itself on resizing the viewport.

In IE the video is tiny and the window is in upper left corner. You may need to scroll up to see it.

=============

I came back to edit this post to improve its quality. Poor quality posts have caused me to be banned, so I'm trying to rehabilitate myself!

The fancybox issue here was caused by structural problems in the code, including having head elements appear before the doctype was seven declared. I inherited the site and it's code, but I still should have corrected the structure to see if that resolved things.  Instead, I took the easy way out and came here.

Sorry, guys... if I get off the banned list, I promise to do better!

Comment: What did you do in attempt to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `DOCTYPE` should be **the very first line** of your html document but you have a bunch of preceding stuff before it :

```
<title>Education Interface | Healthcare Industry Web-Enabled Online Training</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="Education Interface, healthcare, web enabled, online training, learning management system">

<meta name="description" content="Education Interface specializes in providing web-enables online learning to the healthcare industry. We provide solutions that include training, a learning management system, and customized content creation. ">

<style type="text/css">
    #errorMessage
    {
        color:red;
        font-size:10;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

....actually that should be placed inside your `<head>` tag.

Because of that, your page is running in quirks mode, hence the improper style format in both, Safari and IE (fancybox requires your page running in standards mode to work properly)

There is a tool called "validator service" that allows you to find those errors quickly http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.educationinterface.com/

Comment: I 'inherited' the code but should have fixed the structure before try to get something to work in IE.  Thanks.